# SSIS Access DB - Multiple-step OLE DB operation generated errors while executing SQL Procedure

Tags: sql-server, ssis

When I am executing a Procedure with output parameters using SQL Task, I am getting the below mentioned error. There is no problem in db connection, number of passing params, sequence of params and data type.

Command for execution
EXEC [dbo].[spArchiveTablesCleanup] ? OUTPUT, ? OUTPUT, ? OUTPUT

Error:
[Execute SQL Task] Error: Executing the query "EXEC [dbo].[spArchiveTablesCleanup] ? OUTPUT, ? OU..." failed with the following error: "Multiple-step OLE DB operation generated errors. Check each OLE DB status value, if available. No work was done.". Possible failure reasons: Problems with the query, "ResultSet" property not set correctly, parameters not set correctly, or connection not established correctly.

SSIS Parameter Mapping:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yOrVz.png)

SSIS Variable Declaration:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fKYT5.png)

SQL Server procedure params definition:  
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rq4bo.png)

Answer (score 0):

Remove 'OUTPUT' from your EXEC statement. I don't believe you actually need to have that there.

https://www.sqlshack.com/execute-sql-tasks-in-ssis-output-parameters-vs-result-sets/

Answer (score 0):

I have changed the Output parameter Data Type from NUMERIC to LONG, it worked perfectly.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dHueO.png)

Answer (score 0):

I also had this problem and I was able to solve it by checking the variables that I had assigned in the SSIS task that I no longer used.